# Java - Image Rotation

Tags: java, image, graphics, rotation, bufferedimage

I am trying to rotate image. I am using this Java code:

```
BufferedImage oldImage = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("C:\\workspace\\test\\src\\10.JPG"));
BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(oldImage.getHeight(), oldImage.getWidth(), oldImage.getType());
Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) newImage.getGraphics();
graphics.rotate(Math.toRadians(90), newImage.getWidth() / 2, newImage.getHeight() / 2);
graphics.drawImage(oldImage, 0, 0, oldImage.getWidth(), oldImage.getHeight(), null);
ImageIO.write(newImage, "JPG", new FileOutputStream("C:\\workspace\\test\\src\\10_.JPG"));
```

But I see strange result:

Source:

[image: **Sourse image:**]

Result:

[image: **Result image:**]

Can you please help me with this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't you rotate about the center of oldImage, rather than newImage?

Comment: I try 

graphics.rotate(Math.toRadians(90), oldImage.getWidth() / 2, oldImage.getHeight() / 2);


Its not help. http://s13.postimage.org/7omxa1oef/image.jpg

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not enough to switch the width and height of the image. You are rotating using the center of the image as the origin of rotation. Just try the same with a sheet of paper and you will see it works the same way. You must also move the paper a little bit, which means to apply a transform to fix this. So, immediately after the rotate call, do this:

```
  graphics.translate((newImage.getWidth() - oldImage.getWidth()) / 2, (newImage.getHeight() - oldImage.getHeight()) / 2);
```

Comment: I feel ashamed for not immediately thinking of this... :-p

Answer (score 0):

The new image has different sizes because of the rotate.
try this:
BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage( oldImage.getWidth(),oldImage.getHeight(),oldImage.getType());

Comment: Uh, he is very aware there are different sizes. Your code doesn't solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting bounds of your panel on which you do your drawing

```
Rectangle rect = this.getBounds();
```

And then do:

```
graphics.rotate(Math.toRadians(90), (rect.width - newImage.getWidth()) / 2, (rect.height - newImage.getHeight()) / 2);
```

Hope that could help
Cheers!

Comment: was late for a minute ... well :P

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this it will be work.

```
BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(oldImage.getWidth(), oldImage.getHeight(), oldImage.getType());
```

I think the place for `width` and `height` is wrong in your code.