# How can I create a method in Java that rotates an image 90 degrees clockwise?

Tags: java, rotation

This is what I have so far:

```
public static Photograph rotated(Photograph photo) {
    Photograph rotated_copy = new Photograph(photo.getHeight(), photo.getWidth());
    Pixel starting_pixel = photo.getPixel(0,0);

    for(int col = 0; col < photo.getWidth(); col++){
        for(int row = 0; row < photo.getHeight(); row++){
            starting_pixel = photo.getPixel(col,row);
            rotated_copy.setPixel(row, col, starting_pixel);
        }
    }
    return rotated_copy;
}
```

However, this method rotates any Photograph taken in 90 degrees counter-clockwise. How can I fix this?

Comment: 90* counter-clockwise = x* clockwise. Find x and rethink the method.

Comment: Are you sure this really rotates it by 90 degrees? It just switches all the row indexes with columns... For example pixel 0,0 stays on 0,0, right?

Comment: In fact, I think it just switches the picture with the center being the x=-y function...

Comment: Your code is not rotating the image; it is flipping the image (mirroring the image along the line where x=y).

Comment: Ah crap Big Al. In that case, how would I make it rotate?

Comment: Big Al is wrong, your code is indeed rotating. You've tested it, right? And the problem is counter-clockwise? So why are you listening to him saying its flipping?

Comment: Yeah Zaphod, I tested it and it's rotating counter-clockwise.

Comment: I think here is your response:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165977/java-image-rotation

Comment: @Zaphod42 No, it's not rotating. The element at `[0][0]` always remains the same and also the element at `[rowscount][colscount]`. Take a look at [this IDEOne example with a simple int array](http://ideone.com/unxMJ6)

Comment: Can you use BufferedImage instead?

Comment: @AliAlamiri the actual object implementation does not matter. You can do getPixel and setPixel with BufferedImage too. BufferedImage may have a convenient rotate method, but his point still stands.

Comment: "Ah crap Big Al. In that case, how would I make it rotate" ... you think its rotate because it changes the picture, but `it does not rotate` it switch the picture with x=-y function as center

Comment: Yeah, its actually mirroring the image across both axis, which makes it seem almost like its rotating but it isn't. I've modified my answer to point him in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static Photograph rotated(Photograph photo) {
    Photograph rotated_copy = new Photograph(photo.getHeight(), photo.getWidth());
    Pixel starting_pixel = photo.getPixel(0,0);

    for(int col = 0; col < photo.getWidth(); col++){
        for(int row = 0; row = photo.getHeight(); row++){
            starting_pixel = photo.getPixel(col,row);
            rotated_copy.setPixel(photo.getHeight() - row - 1, col, starting_pixel);
        }
    }
    return rotated_copy;
}
```

I think.

Comment: lol, do you know that you did EXACTLY the same as the author but in different order? :)

Comment: Corrected it now (hopefully this time it'll work - I know what to do, but my spatial imagination is kinda weak today ;) )

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Hm, unfortunately that's close but doesn't quite work. Its reflecting the image while it rotates it. You could fix that though:

Instead of placing the co-ordinates in their opposite (X in Y and Y in X), you have to store them in a different order.

Think about the problem. After a 90' clockwise rotation, the co-ordinates (0,0) (0,HEIGHT) should become (0, HEIGHT), (WIDTH, 0) right?

So instead of:

```
starting_pixel = photo.getPixel(col,row);
rotated_copy.setPixel(row, col, starting_pixel);
```

you need something like

```
starting_pixel = photo.getPixel(col,row);
rotated_copy.setPixel(photo.getWidth() - row, col, starting_pixel);
```

Comment: Sry man, if you do it as "X becomes Y, Y becomes X", can you explain me, how the hell pixel on left top corner at {0,0} rotate to the right top corner {max_width,0} or to the left bottom corner {0,max_height}? :)

Comment: @libik ah okay you're right, its both rotating and mirroring the image, so that's not quite right. I've modified my answer.